# Get the value only when passing data from laravel to json

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a query in laravel that I want to pass in json. Problem is both the key and value gets passed to the variable I assigned . I tried passing   **$data= json_encode($ip);** inside the controller and return it in the view but I only get one result. How can I get the value only?

Controller

```
public function displayIP()
{
    $ipadd = DB::table('seatplan_client')->select('ipadd')->get();

    foreach ($ipadd as $ipadds)
    {
        $ip = $ipadds->ipadd;
        $data= json_encode($ip);//test
        echo $data;

    }

    return View::make('seatplan')->with('ipadd',$ipadd);
}
```

View

```
<script> var takenSeats = {{ json_encode($ipadd) }}</script>
```

Result in Page Source

```
var takenSeats = [{"ipadd":"192.168.240.1"},{"ipadd":"192.168.240.2"},{"ipadd":"192.168.240.23"},{"ipadd":"192.168.240.38"}]
```

Comment: What do you expect to be the output? `var takenSeats = [{"0":"192.168.240.1"},{"1":"192.168.240.2"},{"2":"192.168.240.23"},{"3":"192.168.240.38"}]` ?

Comment: @KA_lin var takenSeats = ["192.168.240.1", "192.168.240.2", "192.168.240.23", "192.168.240.38"];

Comment: Do you have a model binded to this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an array that "translates" your object:

```
$ipadsArray = array();
foreach ($ipadd as $ipadds)
{
    $ipadsArray[] = $ipadds->ipadd;
}
return View::make('seatplan')->with('ipadd',$ipadsArray);
```

You need to do this because you are using laravel's ORM which returns stdObjects and when you serialize it you also get the public properties.

If you have a model you could implement [serializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) interface

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> var takenSeats = {{ json_decode($ipadd) }}</script>
```

This will convert your json array to php array. You can omit the keys if you don't want to use it.